# Where can I watch "Y School Heroes" in America?

Tags: yokai-watch

I like to find the *Yo-kai Watch* anime 6, except it only aired in Japan and I can only find the movie. If anyone knows where or how to find [*Y School Heroes*](https://yokaiwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Y_School_Heroes) (original: *Yōkai Wotchi Jam: Yōkai Gakuen Y ~N to no Sōgū~*) on any website in America.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.